# How to run another command after my package is installed using pip?

Tags: python, installation, pip, setuptools, pypi

I'm a Python developer who is releasing a JupyterLab widget extension. To install a JupyterLab widget extension, there are two steps a user must perform two steps:

1. `pip install mitosheet`. The user actually installs my package.
2. `jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager@2`. This commands actually adds widgets to JupyterLab, and then rebuilds JupyterLab, which is a necessary step for proper installation.

I'm looking to get rid of the second step, if it all possible. It seems like 60% or so of the users who install don't run the second command properly, and so installation does not complete.

How do I make it so my `pip install mitosheet` command also properly runs the command `jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager@2`? A key component here is that the `mitosheet` package has to finished being installed before the labextension is installed.

So -- how do I add a post install script after my pip install command? Note that the script has to actually run after `mitosheet` is completely installed, so that things work correctly.

Thanks for any information!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsetuptools%5D+%22post-install+script%22

Comment: In short: no way. `pip` is not a full-blown package manager.